# How to mock a private method which is taking List type as a parameter using power mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

Hi everyone I am trying to mock a private method which is taking List type as a parameter Some part of code details are following:

**CustomerVerification Class**

```
    public class CustomerVerification{

creditCheck.setSuffix(null);
        String pinAndPreciseId = null;
        try {
            pinAndPreciseId = executeCreditCheck(creditCheck, errorResponses, transactionId);
            if (pinAndPreciseId.contains("Error")) {
                ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("EXPERIAN", pinAndPreciseId, "E01", transactionId);
                errorResponses.add(errorResponse);
                customerVerification.setErrorResponses(errorResponses);
                return customerVerification;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new EnterpriseCustomerVerificationException(e.getMessage());
        } 

        }
```

**executeCriditCheck class**

```
private String executeCreditCheck(CreditCheck creditCheck, List<ErrorResponse> errorResponses, String transactionId)
            throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException {
        LOG.info("Calling experian");
        String pinAndPreciseId = null;
        String request = null;
        String referenceId = null;
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date today = new Date();
        referenceId = formatter.format(today);

        HttpPost experianHttpPost = getExperianHttpPostMethod();
        NetConnectRequest netConnectRequest = ExperianCreditMapper.map(creditCheck, eai, dbHost, referenceId,
                experianProduct, opInitials, preamble, subCode, arfVersion, venderNumber, vendorVersion, null,
                CustomRRDashKeyword);
        System.err.println("REQUEST -- " + netConnectRequest.toString());
        request = "NETCONNECT_TRANSACTION=" + URLEncoder.encode(netConnectRequest.toString());

        experianHttpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(request.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        HttpResponse response = experianHttpClient.execute(experianHttpPost);
        pinAndPreciseId = ExperianCreditMapper.getPIN(response);
        return pinAndPreciseId;
    }
```

Can someone give me just an Idea about how to mock **private method executeCreditCheck** which is taking 3 parameters among which one is List type.

> **Note:** I have given just some portion of the code here. Please some one give
>   me an Idea about how to mock **executeCreditCheck** method.

Comment: A) you would look into using spies here. B) Basically you have hard-to-test code here. Instead of getting that somehow tested, rather step back and think up ways to improve your design ... so that it becomes easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

There is huge debate on weather to test private method  not or how to test. Personally, I don't test private method directly. There would be public method that call private method and I prefer indirect testing which I might be doing wrong.

Back to your question,

you can use powermock Whitebox.invokeMethod() for testing private methods. Its syntax is

```
WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(<class object>, “<Name of the private Method>",input param1, input param2,…);
```

Comment: I support yout point of not testing private methods since this test may usually break during *refactorings* where you modified the *implelentation* wihtout changing the behavior. But UnitTests should brake only if the units *behavior* changes in order to be safe guards during refactorings.